# Django serializer field not working

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I did not find a solution although I looked at the questions asked...

When I use this serializer:

```
class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    sender = UserMobileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Messages
        fields = '__all__'
```

I get something like this:

```
{
    "id": 62,
    "sender": {
        "pk": 12,
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "full_name": "John",
        "profile_photo": null
    },
    "created_at": "2018-04-29T00:54:50.437662",
    "message": "sdkjnasljdhkajsjdlasdasda",
    "read_at": false,
    "target": 18
}
```

I would like the `target` field to be like `sender`, that is: display the full user information instead of just the ID.

I tried to add this line: `target = UserMobileSerializer()`, but I still get only the ID in the output. I also tried `target = UserMobileSerializer(read_only=True)` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the field you defined to the `fields` in the serializer's `Meta`. Try this:

```
class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    sender = UserMobileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Messages
        fields = ('your', 'fields', 'sender')
```

EDIT: You need to serialize `target`, too. Like this:

```
class TargetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Target
        fields = ('id', 'title')  # Add fields you want to get in the response.


class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    target = TargetSerializer(read_only=True)  # You should have TargetSerializer defined
    sender = UserMobileSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Messages
        fields = ('your', 'fields', 'target', 'sender')
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but what should be in the inside of the TargetSerializer is the target must come from the user model?

Comment: `TargetSerializer` should be a separate serializer, `ModelSerializer` in your case. You can set it to have `fields` you want to get in the response. I am adding and example on my answer.